# WooCommerce Multiple Email

Tags: woocommerce

We have already set multiple email addresses based on cart qty. For example, if someone orders 4 items, they are required to enter the name, email, contact 4 times.

The problem is I want an email to be sent to all 4 people upon successful transaction.

Here is the code we got and it doesn't send to all 4 people:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'woocommerce_new_order_email_bcc_copy', 10, 4 );
function woocommerce_new_order_email_bcc_copy( $headers, $email_id, $order, $email = null ) {
global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
$i = 0;

if ( !empty($order) ) {
    foreach($items as $item => $values) {
        $i++;
        if( !empty($email = $order->get_meta('patient_email'.$i)) ) { // replace with your meta key name
            $names = $order->get_meta('patient_fullname'.$i);
            $headers .= ' '.$names.' <'.$email.'>,' . "\r\n";
        }
    }

}return 'Cc: '.$headers;
}
```